# Apply drop down list parameters to an array of rows

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have created a drop down list with 2 columns of Data - Name and DOB.  I have a VBA code in place for the drop down to display the data in column 1 for selection but the cell displays the date from column 2.  this works fine.  However, I need the VBA code to apply to multiple rows. When I insert new rows, I want to be able to add this new row into the code and have the drop down list parameters apply.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Updateby Extendoffice
    selectedNa = Target.Value
 *  ** If Target.Row = 7 Then***
        selectedNum = Application.VLookup(selectedNa, ActiveSheet.Range("listrates1"), 2, False)
        If Not IsError(selectedNum) Then
            Target.Value = selectedNum
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is the code that I have.... **If Target.row = 7 then **  - this works great if I select Row 7, however I need the code to work for rows, 7, 10, 13, 16, and so on ......

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Mod function to test for every third row . . .

```
If Target.Row >= 7 Then
    If Target.Row Mod 3 = 1 Then
        'etc
        '
        '
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Thank you so very much - It is wonderful to have a solution to an issue that has been troubling me for some time.  It has worked wonderfully.  Thank you again